# Java applets: How do games like Runescape preload and save resources so the user doesn't have to download them again later?

Tags: java, applet, preload

The first time a user plays Runescape (which is played via Java applet), the applet takes a few minutes to download a large amount of data.  On subsequent plays, this data is retrieved not from the server, but from somewhere on the client's PC.

Where is this data saved to, and how is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively to signing your applet, you could give your applet a [JNLP file](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jws/developersguide/syntax.html)<s>, which will give it access to the [javax.jnlp](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/) package. You can then use `DownloadService` to do caching of data you download.</s>  This will cause Java Web Start to cache your files.

Comment: JWS does not require the `DownloadService` in order to cache classes.  Caching classes is the default behavior (unless disabled via the Java Control Panel).  Specifying lazy downloads and using the `DownloadService` does provide more control, though.

Comment: Ooops. I fixed my answer regarding that.

Comment: Good call!  I'd up-vote the edit, except that I had already up-voted the answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

RuneScape uses a signed applet which gives them access to the file system.

If you look in `c:\.jagex_cache_32` or something like that, you'll find the data files.